# Change radio button into normal button - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, radio-button

I was wondering if there is any chance to change the radio button into a normal button like the one that says "Ask Question" on the Stack Overflow main page.

I'm using **woocommerce** with **deposit - partial payment plugin**. The plugin has 2 options, some kind of bar with DEPOSIT and FULL PAYMENT option and the second with radio buttons for the same options.

```
<?php _e( $deposit_option_text, 'woocommerce-deposits' ); ?>


    <span id='deposit-amount'><?php echo $deposit_amount; ?></span>
    <span id='deposit-suffix'><?php echo $suffix; ?></span><br><br>
</label>
<div class="<?php echo $basic_buttons  ? 'basic-switch-woocommerce-deposits' : 'deposit-options switch-toggle switch-candy switch-woocommerce-deposits'; ?>">
    <input id='pay-deposit' name='<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>-deposit-radio'
           type='radio' <?php checked($default_checked ,'deposit'); ?> class='input-radio' value='deposit'>
    <label id="pay-deposit-label" for='pay-deposit'
           onclick=''><?php _e( $deposit_text , 'woocommerce-deposits' ); ?></label>
    <?php if( isset( $force_deposit ) && $force_deposit === 'yes' ){ ?>
        <input id='pay-full-amount' name='<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>-deposit-radio'  type='radio'
               class='input-radio'
               disabled>
        <label id="pay-full-amount-label" for='pay-full-amount'
               onclick=''><?php _e( $full_text , 'woocommerce-deposits' ); ?></label>
    <?php } else{ ?>
        <input id='pay-full-amount' name='<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>-deposit-radio'
               type='radio' <?php checked($default_checked ,'full'); ?> class='input-radio' value='full'>
        <label id="pay-full-amount-label" for='pay-full-amount'
               onclick=''><?php _e( $full_text , 'woocommerce-deposits' ); ?></label>
    <?php } ?>
```

Any idea how to change the 2 radio buttons into regular buttons?

Comment: You can try to style the radio button into You want using pure css(for example by theme styles) without changing the code of plugin You use.

Comment: Hello :) That's right mate, the only problem here is I'm a newbie doing this. Anyway, thank you so much for your answer, honestly :)

Comment: here is simple example http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/9/